# Point-in-time restores of databases and documents using Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, backup, cloudant

How can I save changes in CouchDB / Cloudant in order to later do point-in-time restores of my databases, or even specific documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’re working on making this a first-class feature, but until we roll it out, this is how one of our customers did it:

You have collections, and within those collections, resources. So, you keep a logging database where every document has an ID like `collection-resource`, so for a collection named "cars" and a resource named "Ford", you'd have a document in your logging database named `cars-ford`. That document looks like this:

```
{
  versions: [...]
}
```

Any time that resource is touched or modified, your application updates the logging document by appending the new version to the end of the `versions` field. That version might look like this:

```
{
  timestamp: '...', # some integer timestamp, for sorting
  doc: {...} # attributes of the document as of the save
}
```

We'll use that view to return a list of all versions of all documents, sorted by when each change occurred.

Then, here's how you use that to do restores and the like:

**Getting the most recent version of a resource**

Get the document in its entirety, and grab the last element in the `versions` field. That's the most recent version.

**See all versions relative to a timestamp**

We'll create a view to sort by timestamp. The view looks like this:

```
{
  map: "function(doc) {
      for(var i in doc.versions){
        emit(doc.versions[i].timestamp, doc.versions[i].doc);
      }
    }"
}
```

Say our database is named `loggy`, the design doc where our views live is named `restore`, and the view itself is named `time`. Then we'll make a GET request to this URL:

```
{CLOUDANT_HOST}/loggy/_design/restore/_view/time?startkey='...'
```

...where the value for `startkey` is some timestamp. This, unmodified, will return every version after the indicated timestamp.  Add `limit=X` and you'll get the X versions after the timestamp. Add `descending=true` and you'll get versions before the timestamp, instead of after.

**See the Nth revision for a resource**

Much like above, but we'll tweak our view a little:

```
{
  map: "function(doc){
      for(var i in doc.versions){
        emit(i, doc.versions[i].doc);
      }
    }"
}
```

Now our view results are keyed by index rather than timestamp. So, instead of passing a timestamp to `startkey`, we just pass N to versions around the Nth revision.

**Getting the number of revisions for a collection or resource**

We'll use another view to group by collection and resource:

```
{
  map: "function(doc){
    // split te ID into collection and resource
    var parts = doc._id.split('-');
    // emit them as keys so we can group by them
    emit([doc.parts[0], doc.parts[1]], null);
  }",
  reduce: "_count"
}
```

Use the query parameter `group` and `group_level` to group results by their keys. So, if we want the number of events that have touched resources in the `cars` collection, we would use a querystring like this:

```
?group=true&group_level=1&key="cars"
```

`group` groups results whose keys are the same, but `group_level=1` says "only group on the first key", which in our case is the collection. `key` specifies to only return documents whose key matches the given value.

**Getting all resources for a given collection**

Using the [_all_docs](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/database.html?highlight=_all_docs#get-db-all-docs) view, we'll use a querystring like this:

```
?reduce=false&startkey="{collection}-"&endkey="{collection}0"
```

Remember the `reduce` part of our function? That `_count` value means "return the number of records emitted by `map`". `reduce=false` means "Don't do that." Instead, only the `map` function is run.

That `startkey` and `endkey` pair uses how Cloudant sorts results to exclude everything but the values matching IDs that start with the given collection.

**Updating docs**

Once you've got the versions you'd like to restore, GET the current version of the resource, GET the past version from the loggy database, and PUT the past version to the resource using the current version's `_rev` value. Bam, restored. Rinse and repeat for point-in-time restore.